# Any thoughts on how to remove this faucet / handle

Tags: plumbing, faucet, removal, bathroom-fixtures

Hoping to find some help here as I am at a loss.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to remove this fixture.  There are no brand marks and I don't know who installed it.  The handles don't have any set screws so I can't seem to get them off and when I grab the neck piece I can't seem to get it to unscrew.

[image: Full view of faucet]

[image: Underneath faucet]

[image: Faucet with spout removed]

Answer (score 2):

It may be a Kohler or at least have the same design. Try this :

> 1  Hold on to the handle while turning the handle base counterclockwise by hand or with a strap wrench, taking care to protect the finish.
>
> 2  Remove any remaining components to expose the valve. Set all parts aside for re-use.
>
> 3  The valve can now be replaced or other repairs made.
>
> 4  Reassemble handle parts in reverse order.

https://support.kohler.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002095334-Remove-the-Handles-for-the-Finial-Bathroom-or-Kitchen-Faucet

Comment: You were spot-on with the rubber strap wrench I was able to get the handles off but since it looks like it's a plug-and-play system I'm trying to identify what faucet I can get as a replacement I still can't seem to get the bases off and I don't know if it's something that I'm doing wrong or if they could have glue down or something but after putting a pair of vice grips on the basis I still couldn't get them off