# How do you remove the handles on this faucet

Tags: faucet

[image: faucets]
I'm trying to repair a leak in both faucets in this sink.

I think the first step is to remove the faucet but can't figure out how to do this.

I can't see a set screw. I tried gently prying with a screwdriver. I tried unscrewing the skirt by hand. I tried unscrewing the handle parts. These appear to be caulked on. There is no brand name visible.

I don't want to use too much force if doing it the wrong way.

Do I have to remove by undoing the nut on the supply line? There isn't a lot of room to access these nuts so not sure what tool to use, which is why I haven't attempted this. The whole thing looks fairly old since the supply line is a solid metal tube, not flexible.

Any ideas on how to remove these faucets?

Comment: Hold handle steady while turning the base counterclockwise. You may be able to do  this by hand or might need a strap wrench

Comment: See this https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/151923/46271. Very similar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any thoughts on how to remove this faucet / handle](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/151914/any-thoughts-on-how-to-remove-this-faucet-handle)

Comment: I believe there is cap on the back of the handle that pops off, closets part to faucet. You then loosen a screw there to remove the handle. The rest then screws off or lifts off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: faucet disassembled]

Thank you Kris -- it was possible to unscrew the base. I ended up using a basin wrench to loosen the locking nut underneath the sink a tiny bit and then that made it really easy to loosen the faucet by hand.

Comment: Welcome back, and thanks for posting your own solution. You can mark your answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark; it won't give you points, but it'll help future people with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

The logo on the sink below the overflow says **KOHLER**. They are very helpful if you just give them a call 1 (800) 456-4537. I would say a simple email to one of their specialists will have you going in no time.